# Not redirecting to PUT(Update action) in rails when updating a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am stuck with a strange issue. I have googled and tried everything that was possible. All in vain and I am at the same place.

Listing the details

I have a route in routes file as **resources :projects**

The routes generated is as

admin_projects GET

```
                                                    /admin/projects(.:format)                                   admin/projects#index
                                           POST     /admin/projects(.:format)                                   admin/projects#create
                          new_admin_project GET     /admin/projects/new(.:format)                               admin/projects#new
                         edit_admin_project GET      /admin/projects/:id/edit(.:format)                          admin/projects#edit
                              admin_project GET      /admin/projects/:id(.:format)                               admin/projects#show
                                           PUT      /admin/projects/:id(.:format)                               admin/projects#update
                                           DELETE   /admin/projects/:id(.:format)                               admin/projects#destroy*
```

**My form is**

form_for [:admin, @project], format: :js,remote: true, html: {id: 'edit-project-form', :method => :put } do |f|

...form fields

```
<td><%= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn primary save" %></td>
```

The URL being generated and the form tag on inspection is as follow

IF i manually update this **post** to **put** through firebug it gets updated Otherwise its throwing me a **no routes matched error**

(No route matches [POST] "/admin/projects/46.js"):

Please Help me figuring out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

remove 'format: :js' as 'remote: true' will send this as js request.

that is causing the whole issue.

Comment: I tried that also its of no use. I am redirecting I mean rendering a .js.erb file after the controller action.